# Array value display problem in loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have created one array with another array but it is not showing value one by one when i am trying to display the value of it using for loop , just like the parent array.

```
*import array
arr_py = array.array('i',[12,13,14,15,16,17,18])
print(arr_py,'Len of array--->',len(arr_py))
arr_py2 = (arr_py.typecode,[x*3 for x in arr_py])
print(arr_py2)
for i in range(len(arr_py)):
    print('arr_py['+str(i)+']---->',arr_py[i])
for i in range(len(arr_py2)):
    print('arr_py2['+str(i)+']---->',arr_py2[i])*
```

Please help me to find out where i am wrong.

Regards
Anutosh

Answer (score 0):

You simply omitted the array definition when creating the `arr_py2` array.  So it became a tuple instead of array.  Just update that assignment statement to this:

```
arr_py2 = array.array(arr_py.typecode,[x*3 for x in arr_py])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import array
arr_py = array.array('i',[12,13,14,15,16,17,18])
print(arr_py,'Len of array--->',len(arr_py))
#arr_py2 = (arr_py.typecode,[x*3 for x in arr_py])
arr_py2 = [x*3 for x in arr_py]
print(arr_py2)
for i in range(len(arr_py)):
    print('arr_py['+str(i)+']---->',arr_py[i])
for i in range(len(arr_py2)):
    print('arr_py2['+str(i)+']---->',arr_py2[i])
```

correct answer

arr_py2[0]----> 36
arr_py2[1]----> 39
arr_py2[2]----> 42
arr_py2[3]----> 45
arr_py2[4]----> 48
arr_py2[5]----> 51
arr_py2[6]----> 54